# Hasse principle and twists of $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $X$ be a twist of the $n$-th projective space, seen as a $K$-variety for some number field $K$. For $n = 1$, the Hasse principle holds for $X$.

> My question is: for which $n >1$ does the Hasse principle also hold?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question, Projective space has a rational point, so the Hasse principle trivially holds. Are you interested in whether the Hasse principle holds for Brauer-Severi varieties (i.e. twists of projective space)? Here the Hasse principle is classical and can be proved using class field theory.

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to write twists

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel mentioned, the answer is yes. This is Theorem 4.5.11 in Bjorn Poonen's *[Rational Points on Varieties](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf)*.